# How to use const outside of async function with Prompts library & TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to read the user input and use it outside of the function. How can I do this? I have tried using `return` and `let` statements.

Code:

Prompts.ts

```
export async function botNameValue() {
    const botResp = await prompts({
        type: 'text',
        name: 'botName',
        message: 'Enter Bot Name'
    });
    return botResp;
}
```

Prompt is being executed this way:

```
export async function Prompter() {
    await botNameValue()
    await TokenValue()
    await GuildIDValue()
    await SelectionValue()
}
```

Comment: `botNameValue` returns a value. Did you want to assign that to use elsewhere?

Comment: No, I only want to use this for executing purposes.

Comment: What do you mean by "*for executing purposes*"? How and where do you want to use it?

Comment: Please look above on how the function is being executed.

Comment: Yes, in a way that completely discards the input from the user. Store the return value from the function so you can use it later where you need it. Otherwise, why prompt the user?

Comment: Hint: a `const` declared in a function is not accessible outside of that function.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: `const botResp = await botNameValue()`? Then you use it where you need it, like pass it into another function as a parameter or return it from `Prompter` to use elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me!